Requesting Resources on Algebraic Structure that is Both Ring and Vector Space.
My motivation for this inquiry:
A friend recently introduced me to  algebraic structure called algebra. However, I'm struggling to find suitable learning resources as the term "algebra" often refers to various mathematical concepts, making my search difficult.
The definition he shared with me:
Algebra:
A linear space $A$ is called an algebra if its vectors can be multiplied in such a way that $A$ is also a ring in which scalar multiplication is related to multiplication by the following property:
$\alpha (xy)=( \alpha x)y= x( \alpha y)$.
The concept of algebra is therefore a natural combination of the concepts of a linear space and a ring.
Please provide me with comprehensive resources (books, articles, online courses, etc.) that will enable me to learn about this structure, starting from the fundamentals and progressing to an advanced level.

The case that has vast literature is: Banach algebra.  Including $C^*$ algebra.

Greub Linear Algebra, 4th ed. has nice basic coverage of algebras.

There are many different directions one can go with algebras. Two references toward central simple algebras are Dennis, Farb - Noncommutative algebra and Ford - Separable algebras.

The search term you want is "associative algebra" which should lead to many resources. Related is "noncommutative ring" or "noncommutative algebra" and probably even "ring theory" (they study associative algebras there too). As a sample you can check out Lam's A First Course in Noncommutative Rings or Curtis and Reiner's Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras.
Note that an equivalent definition of an associative algebra $A$ over a field $k$ is that it is a ring together with a ring homomorphism $\varphi : k \to Z(A)$ from $k$ to the center of $A$; this is not entirely obvious and is a nice exercise. So for many basic results $k$ is not so important; for example every $A$-module and in particular every left, right, or two-sided ideal is automatically a $k$-vector space and one does not have to require this, and so any theorems about such modules which are only stated for rings are valid a fortiori for associative algebras with no modification and no need to explicitly mention $k$.
"Algebra" is ambiguous for many reasons but one of them is that sometimes people use it to mean a vector space equipped with a bilinear map $m : A \times A \to A$ without any other constraints, so as to allow the term to include Lie algebras, Jordan algebras, etc.

It might be worth noting that in the same way it is not universally agreed whether rings should be unital, it is not universally agreed whether algebras are either. If we do insist that rings and ring homomorphisms are unital, then a ring $A$ equipped with a ring homomorphism $k\to R$ is both associative and unital. Some authors would call such structures $A$ "algebras", others would call them "associative algebras", and others still would call them "unital associative algebras"!
